# SwiftUI Change icon by number

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want the Images to change according to the text, but it works over .degisim String and int value in the ready-made code block I found. That's why it doesn't work for String.

```
import SwiftUI

struct altin: View {
    
        @State var users: [Altin] = []
    
        var body: some View {
            
            ZStack{
                List(users) { altin in
                    NavigationLink {
                        detayView(altinKur: altin)
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: getImage(percent: Int(altin.degisim)))
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: 9, height: 9)
                                .foregroundColor(
                                    (altin.degisim).contains("-") ?
                                    Color.down :
                                    Color.up)
                                .padding(.trailing, 5)
                                
                                Text(altin.degisim)
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .foregroundColor(
                                        (altin.degisim).contains("-") ?
                                        Color.down :
                                        Color.up)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .padding(0)
                    .onAppear {
                        apiCall().getUsers { (users) in
                            self.users = users
           
           }
        }
    }
}
    
struct altin_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        altin()
            
       }
   }
 

func getImage(percent: Int) -> String{
    if percent > 0 {
        return "chevron.up"
    }else{
        return "chevron.down"
    }
}
```

.foregroundcolor works but not within Image.
The code is more complex, I simplified it for solution.

Model:

```
struct Altin: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let alis: String
    let satis: String
    let degisim: String
}
```

Comment: what is `degisim` and values can it have?

Comment: if it is a positive or negative decimal number as a string, just use: `Int(Double(altin.degisim) ?? 0))`

Comment: .degisim is not a number actually String, I need to write it as a string

Comment: Would `degisim` be read by a human as a number?

Comment: https://www.hizliresim.com/qaba5wz

Comment: I think it's clear what I want to do in the picture.

Comment: Why don’t you use fie getImage the same test you use for computing foreground color ?

Comment: I want to use icon, the code to use color doesn't work. Your icon needs to turn from the law or 180 degrees. I couldn't find what to write.

Comment: Your function can work with a string : If degisim.contains(‘-‘) return up else return down